# Implementing fullscreen on a video not using modal window

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing a video controller without controls from [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video).

Because I need to display other buttons like a double speed.

What I want to do is implementing a fullscreen not using modal window.

And I hope implementing easily like using a library.


So, is there any solution about that more easy way?

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';

...

<View>
  <Video
    ref={videoPlayer}
    paused={movie_pause_status}
    source={vimeo}
    autoplay={true}
    muted={false}
    repeat={false}
    volume={1.0}
    rate={videoSpeed}
    onProgress={onProgress}
    style={styles.mediaPlayer}
    ignoreSilentSwitch={'ignore'}
    playInBackground={true}
    pictureInPicture={false}
    />
 <View style={styles.content1}>
   <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={() => {
       setVideoSpeed(2.0);
     }}>
     <Image
       style={styles.content2}
       source={require('../../images/double_speed.png')}
     />
   </TouchableOpacity>
  <View style={styles.content3}>
    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>
      {arrange_video_time()}
    </Text>
    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{currentTime}</Text>
      <Slider
        style={{ width: 200, height: 40 }}
        minimumValue={0}
        maximumValue={movie?.duration_second}
        minimumTrackTintColor="#4169e1"
        maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
        value={currentTime}
        onSlidingComplete={unified}
        onSlidingStart={value => changeMoviePauseStatus(true)}
      />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Show us your codes.

Comment: I did it!Thank you for letting me know!